# Qt Quick Desktop application deployment

Tags: qt

I am working on the **Qt Quick Desktop application** and my target is to deliver this application for 3 major Operating system macOS/Windows/Linux. I have completed my project. I have used QtSql and one third party library rncryptorc. Now I just want to distribute my application to the users for testing. Please guide me the step by step guide to deploy the project for macOS. I have **qt creator** installed.

A complete guide for qt quick desktop application deployment.

Comment: Hi, here's a start [Qt for macOS - Deployment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/macos-deployment.html).